# How does one inflate XWalkView in an XML layout (or programmatic)?

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

I'm having a serious problem with a runtime exception when inflating an XML layout that includes the XWalkView...

Stack trace :

```text
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:233)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:237)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.init(ReflectionHelper.java:132)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:199)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper$ConstructorHelper.loadConstructor(ReflectionHelper.java:37)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.createInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:246)
            at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:169)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.bean.project.XWalkUIActivity.onCreate(XWalkUIActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:237)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.init(ReflectionHelper.java:132)
```

XML :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/com_bean_project_content"
  android:theme="@style/com_bean_project_black" >
  
    <!-- bottom controls -->
 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/com_bean_project_bottom_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

  <!-- some buttons, nothing to worry about -->

 </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- fills most of the parent view -->
    <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/com_bean_project_webview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/com_bean_project_bottom_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Things I have done :

1) in Android Studio, I am using the `armeabi-v7a` folder from the library and `xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar` and `xwalk_core_library_java_library_part.jar` both of these are included in the dependencies. I don't know whether I should only use one of those jar's? I couldn't find anything about it in any documents.

2) the activity with XWalkView has `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

3) on the crosswalk downloads page (https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html) I have downloaded version 11.40.277.7 of `Android webview (ARM)`

4) I also merged the "res" folder from crosswalk into my project, but this makes no difference.

5) I've also tried programmatic inflation, however, it also excepts just with a `new XWalkView(mParentActivity, mParentActivity);` (I know, silly constructor):

```text
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:233)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:237)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.init(ReflectionHelper.java:132)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:199)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper$ConstructorHelper.loadConstructor(ReflectionHelper.java:37)
            at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.createInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:246)
            at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:192)
```

For inspiration, I've looked at https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html however, it's no help on this issue.

Comment: did you look at what the error says `java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode`

Comment: yeah I saw that - but I have no idea what it's supposed to do... there's no documentation for it. ? What does it mean by "shared mode". I just want the view in my layout.

Comment: I saw this problem when using an X86 build lib on ARM. I tried running it on an Intel based Android tablet and that worked. HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

At first i also tried to use jars in my app. That didn't work and i got the same exceptions as you.

Then i stumbled upon [this sample app](https://github.com/dougdiego/CrosswalkDemo) that shows how to use Crosswalk.
I then copied the build into my app and everything worked ok.
Here is what i added in my gradle file:
in the repositories section i added one line (below the crashlytics..)

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven'}
maven { url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'}
```

}

In the dependencies section i also added one line - the last one:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15'
```

}

This is the xml for the activity:

```
<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/walk_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

And this is how i use it in the java code:

```
private void setXView(){
    mXview = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.walk_view);
    mXview.load("http://www.cnn.com",null);
}
```

Don't forget to delete the jars in your app or you might get a compilation error if you have fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) in your dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I've marked your text as the answer. But it seems to depend on the version of XWalk being used. You use 10.39.235.15, but I use 12.41.x.x and I need to instantiate XWalkView programmatically, even 11.40.x.x needed programmatic instantiation

Comment: I see. Yes i did overlook the version issue... Not sure my method works on later versions. Have you tried to build this way with 12.41.x.x?

Comment: for xwalkview initilization taking too much time

Comment: hi i load url but issue is my web has some option to select pics from gallery so this option is only working first time after that clicking on button is not showing any option to select pictures from gallery

Answer (score 3):

After a day of insane experimentation, I finally gave up on trying to store a local copy of the library.

Instead, I went with Maven using these instructions: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk/crosswalk_aar.html

At the bottom of that page is a link to a sample app that's set up with Maven - which is useful.

Note: to find out what versions of the library are available, go here: https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/

for example, instead of the "beta" dependency, you would have `compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:12.41.296.5'`

After having it set up with maven, I then reverted to the XML inflation.

However, I was then faced with

```
04-02 16:38:31.036  14165-14165/com.bean.project W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
04-02 16:38:31.037  14165-14165/com.bean.project W/System.err﹕ at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewInternal.<init>(XWalkViewInternal.java:197)
04-02 16:38:31.037  14165-14165/com.bean.project W/System.err﹕ at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.<init>(XWalkViewBridge.java:46)
```

the insanity continues...

```
public XWalkViewInternal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(convertContext(context), attrs);

    checkThreadSafety();
    mActivity = (Activity) context;
    mContext = getContext();
    init(mContext, attrs);
}
```

how can they possibly think that's a good idea ??!! /facepalm

**EDIT:** to get the XWalkView added to a layout programmatically I put a placeholder (empty) RelativeLayout in the XML with ID `FULLSCREEN_YOUTUBE_CONTAINER_ID` and then in onCreate() of the activity I did:

```
mYoutubeVideoViewContainer = (RelativeLayout) mLayoutView.findViewById(FULLSCREEN_YOUTUBE_CONTAINER_ID);
mYoutubeWebView = new XWalkView(mParentActivity, mParentActivity);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.addView(mYoutubeWebView, relativeParams);
```

Comment: hi peresis - I did finally manage to get it to work programmatically. I've edited this answer with the steps.